# foreman.facts in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, foreman

Iam using the [foreman.py](https://github.com/theforeman/foreman_ansible_inventory) script for creating a dynamic inventory. How can I use the collected facts from the foreman.facts file in my ansible playbooks?

```
ll /etc/ansible/foreman*

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  613597 Jun  3 16:38 /etc/ansible/foreman.cache
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1331584 Jun  3 16:38 /etc/ansible/foreman.facts
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root       2 Jun  3 16:38 /etc/ansible/foreman.hostcollections
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   42427 Jun  3 16:38 /etc/ansible/foreman.index
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     506 Jun  3 16:17 /etc/ansible/foreman.ini
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   32539 Jun  3 16:38 /etc/ansible/foreman.params
```

Thank you very much!

Best regards

Comment: What have you tried to use them so far ? Because it should be as simple as using any other fact discovered on any other host in any inventory => `"{{ name_of_var }}"`

Comment: Did you try to inspect `hostvars['somehost']` to see what you get in there ?

Comment: yes, this does not work. :-/ I must load the facts from the generated json file (foreman.facts) because some of my target hosts are not reachable via ssh directry.

I want to use the collected facts for some remote job handling inside the foreman.

Ive tried to include the file on play-level and on task-level. (via vars_files: and include_vars:)

When I print the variables with the mentioned hostvars prefix I can see the content of the whole file!?

- name: Print variable
    debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars['Testhost'] }}"

Answer (score 2):

It's working now!

I've imported the `foreman.facts` file into my ansible-playbook in the following way:

```
vars_files:
  - /etc/ansible/foreman.facts
```

After that, I am able to use the variables. e.g.

```
when: foreman['model_name'] == "VMware Virtual Platform"
```